# Would I say... I'm not at your convenience or I'm not at your convenient?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Things don't just happen when you want it to.
How can I put that in a sentence with the word convenience  or convenient?

Answer (score 1):

Although `at your convenience` sounds *a little* better, both are an awkward way to phrase it. A better way may be to say:

```
I'm not available at your convienience
```

Since a person cannot be at your convenience, this makes more sense.